# how can i write nested recursive function in matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion, factorial

```
    I want to write nested recursive function. 
    Example: Calculate sum of factorial of 1 to n numbers.
```

myfact(n) function calculate factorial of n.

```
function [ fact ] = myfact( x )
temp = 0;
if (x == 1)
    temp = 1;
else
    temp = x*myfact(x-1);
end
fact = temp;
end
```

myfactSum() function calculate the sum of return values of "myfact".
factNums is an array which contains each value's factorial. For example : factNums(2)=2!

```
function [total] = myfactSum(n,factNums)
    if(n==1)
       return
    else
    result = myfact(n);
    factNums(n) = result;
    total=sum(factNums);
    myfactSum(n-1,factNums);
    end
end
```

Testing it script above ;

```
n = 4;
factNums = zeros(1,n);
x=myfactnum(n,factNums);

y=0;
for i=1:checkValues
   y=y+myfact(i); 
end
```

At the results of script **x=24, y=33**
One recursive and loop find right answer, however nested recursive functions return only the factorial of last value.
I try to debug the recursive functions, it fill the factNums with values [1,2,6,24] end of the function values, but when it back to main script values dissapeared.

[image: variable values after i run the script]

Comment: You are returning `total=sum(factNums)`, this is one value, the sum of `[1,2,6,24]` which is correctly output as `33`. Just don't do the sum if you don't want the sum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change myfactSum, and it works :) It is so simple :)

```
function [sum] = myfactnum(n)

temp=1;    
    if(n==0)
       temp=0;
    else
    temp=myfact(n)+myfactnum(n-1);
    end
sum=temp;    
end
```